# Noobie Error: THREE.Object3D.add: object not an instance of THREE.Object3D

Tags: javascript, three.js, classloader, loader

[Picture of error in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kEeF.png)

Hi all, I am getting this error but I am an amateur coder that is simply trying to learn from a course on YouTube.
I previously tried troubleshooting it and changing things around, but I don't understand the solution. This is quite a big undertaking even following a tutorial. I haven't done coding since my first 2 years of Computer Science before I switched(3 years ago).

Checking other posts with this issue the common solution seems to be adding .scene when importing but is it just an issue with the Resources.js or across the board I did something wrong.

```
import * as THREE from "three";

import { EventEmitter } from "events";
import { GLTFLoader } from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js";
import { DRACOLoader } from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/DRACOLoader.js";
import Experience from "../Experience.js";

export default class Resources extends EventEmitter{
    constructor(assets){
        super();
        this.experience = new Experience();
        this.renderer = this.experience.renderer;

    this.assets = assets;

    this.items = {};
    this.queue = this.assets.length;
    this.loaded = 0;

    this.setLoaders();
    this.startLoading();
}

setLoaders() {
    this.loaders = {};
    this.loaders.gltfLoader = new GLTFLoader();
    this.loaders.dracoLoader = new DRACOLoader();
    this.loaders.dracoLoader.setDecoderPath("/draco/");
    this.loaders.gltfLoader.setDRACOLoader(this.loaders.dracoLoader);
}
startLoading() {
    for (const asset of this.assets){
        if(asset.type === "glbModel") {
            this.loaders.gltfLoader.load(asset.path, (file)=> {
                this.singleAssetLoaded(asset, file);
            });
        }else if (asset.type === "videoTexture"){
            this.video = {};
            this.videoTexture = {};

            this.video[asset.name] = document.createElement("video");
            this.video[asset.name].src = asset.path;
            this.video[asset.name].muted = true;
            this.video[asset.name].playsInLine = true;
            this.video[asset.name].autoplay = true;
            this.video[asset.name].loop = true;
            this.video[asset.name].play();

            this.videoTexture[asset.name] = new THREE.VideoTexture(this.video[asset.name]);

            this.videoTexture[asset.name].flipY = true;
            this.videoTexture[asset.name].minFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
            this.videoTexture[asset.name].magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
            this.videoTexture[asset.name].generateMipmaps = false;
            this.videoTexture[asset.name].encoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;

            this.singleAssetLoaded(asset, this.videoTexture[asset.name]);
        }
    }
}

singleAssetLoaded(asset, file) {
    this.items[asset.name] = file;
    this.loaded++;

    
    if(this.loaded === this.queue){
        this.emit("ready");
    }
}
```

}

[ENVIRONMENT.JS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLWhS.png)

Comment: The problem seems to be in `Environment.js`. You should post that file with you question.